# Compare NSMutableArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, comparison

I have two NSMutabaleArrays. Say, Suppose I have 2 arrays,

array1={A,B, Y,E,P,Q,M,S,R,Q}
array2={Y,L,T}

I want to check values of array2 is there in array 1 and get the result, if  all the values are there return null and if any values are not there put it in an array.

Comment: This sounds like a relatively easy task. Have you tried writing code for it?

Comment: So you want an array of the difference? Is order important (will you sort afterwards)?

Comment: for (id object in array2)
        {
            if ([array1 containsObject:object])
            {
                
            }
        }

Comment: Order is not important I just want array of difference.

Comment: I want see if array2 values are in array1. If not then I have to do some functionality of those values which are not there.

Comment: @user2903572 - Why did you reject your `for` loop solution given in your comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing NSMutableArray Elements for Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346750/comparing-nsmutablearray-elements-for-values)

Answer (score 3):

Since according to the comments the order does not matter for you, the easiest way to achieve this would be using `NSSet`:

```
NSArray *array0 = @[@"A", @"B",@"C",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I"];
NSArray *array1 = @[@"E", @"H"];
NSMutableSet *result = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array0];
[result minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray:array1]];
```

Comment: While its not completely clear I think the OP wants array1 - array0; of course your approach works either way around!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`

```
NSIndexSet *indexesOfObjectsNotInArray1 = [array2 indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [array1 indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:obj] == NSNotFound;
}];
NSArray *objectsNotInArray1 = [array2 objectsAtIndexes:indexesOfObjectsNotInArray1];
```

Comment: array1={A,B, Y,E,P,Q,M,S,R,Q}
array2={Y,L,T} For this array, I am not able to get the result, L and T.

Comment: Works for me when I test with two arrays of `NSString` objects. Are you sure that the arrays are initialized when you perform the above code? What result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over both of the arrays and then compare the objects.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array2 count]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < [array1 count]; j++) {
            if (![[array1 objectAtIndex:j] isEqual:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                // objects are different
                // manipulate the objects here (use index j to reference object in array1)
                NSLog(@"array 1 index %d (%@) and array 2 index %d (%@) are unequal", j, [array1 objectAtIndex:j], i, [array2 objectAtIndex:i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use `isEqual:` to compare two objects, since `!=` compares their address in memory, not the value of string.